# CP Script Messing Up File Names

Tags: ssh, cp

I'm SSHing onto a server to run a script that contains about 250,000 lines like the following:

```
cp directory_a/file_1.jpg new_directory/file_1.jpg
cp directory_b/file_2.jpg new_directory/file_2.jpg
```

Each file name is unique.  Some of the names of the new files are glitching.  For example, `file_1.jpgg,` or `file_2.jpggg`.  Any ideas about why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a problem with the source file or the destination file?

Comment: It's a problem with the destination files, but some of the source files don't exist.  Atleast, I'm assuming some of the source files don't exist because I get an error that says "cp: cannot access directory_x/file_y.jpg."

Comment: There isn't enough information here to give any useful advice. `cp` doesn't randomly "glitch" filenames. If "Some of the names of the new files are glitching", the simplest explanation is that this script has some glitchy filenames in it.

Comment: There aren't any glitchy filenames.  `grep -v "[\x80-\xFF]" copy_files.sh` doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my script had Windows line endings, but I was running it on a Linux machine.  I changed the line-endings to Unix line endings, and it works perfectly now.